# Adding together the values of the elements in a vector in R

Tags: r, fibonacci

I am new to R and am trying to determine the answer to the second of the Euler Project questions. I was able to create a Fibonacci sequence with the following code:

> l<- 50
>   y <- numeric(l)
>   y[1] <- 1
>   y[2] <- 2
>   for(i in 3:l) {
>           + y[i] <- y[i-1] + y[i-2] }

this gave me:

> y
>        [1]           1           2           3           5           8          13                  21
>        [8]          34          55          89         144         233         377             610
>       [15]         987        1597        2584        4181        6765       10946

and so on...

My next step in solving this problem requires me to add all even values of this vectors elements. I know this requires    y %% 2 == 0, to get all TRUE values, however I have not found a way to summate the values of the elements in this vectors. Despite searching google and the help files, I was not able to find an answer.

I am asking if anyone can pose a solution to this problem based off my previous code for determining the Fibonacci sequence. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an extra '+' in your code so I've recreated here with this removed.

```
l <- 50
y <- numeric(l)
y[1] <- 1
y[2] <- 2
for(i in 3:l) {
  y[i] <- y[i-1] + y[i-2] }
```

Then, to subset vector based on TRUE values just put condition in square brackets:

```
evenY <- y[y %%2 == 0]
```

and then sum.  In one line:

```
sum(y[y %%2 == 0])
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. However the '+' is from pressing command + enter within R to create a new line of code (I should just code in word pad then run that code in R).